# c# draw linklabel on usercontrol

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I'm designing a `UserControl` that will hold a list of `linklabel`s. Something like this:

```
public class ItemControl : LinkLabel {}

public class ItemsControl : UserControl
{
    private readonly List<ItemControl> items;

    public TaskBox()
    {
        this.items = new List<ItemControl>();
    }

    public List<ItemControl> Items
    {
        get { return this.items; }
    }
}
```

But how can I draw the items on the `UserControl` once I add them to the list? Also how can I add the clicked event to them in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a `FlowLayoutPanel` control on your `ItemsControl` and use following code to draw `ItemControl`s to it:

```
foreach (var item in this.Items)
{
      flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(item);
      item.LinkClicked += item_LinkClicked;
}

void item_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
      MessageBox.Show(((item)sender).Name);
}
```

Using `FlowLayaoutPanel` is arbitrary, but If you don't use `FlowLayoutPanel`, you can put each `LinkItem` directly on your `UserControl`, and have to manage each `LinkItem` location, yourself.